# CSS image formatting with NG-Repeat angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i'm trying to format my angularJS images that populate the html, i have been trying to get the images next to each other so that 4 images display then it goes onto a new line so they are displayed in rows of 4 but when the code is coming from angular it doesn't seem to like it.. here is my html :

```
<span ng-repeat="x in r.selectedImageUri">
    <div style="width:25%;position:inline-block;">
         <img ng-src="{{x}}" width="100%" alt="image" style="">
         <div><button class="button button-assertive" style="width:100%;">Deletee</button></div>
    </div>          
 </span>
```

Also here is a screenshot of what it looks like

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mhzz.png)

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> style="width:25%;position:inline-block;"
> ```

```
style="width:25%;display:inline-block;"
```

> ```
> width="100%" alt="image" style=""
> ```

```
style="width:100%" alt="image"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `display: inline-block` not `position`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
                <span ng-repeat="x in r.selectedImageUri">
                <div style="width:100%;">

                     <div class="col">
                    <img ng-src="{{x}}" width="100%" style="max-width:200px;" alt="image" style="">
                    <div><button class="button button-assertive" style="width:100%;">Deletee</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </span>
                </div>
```